# Calibrate Graphic EQ without SPL Meter

Tags: equalization

I have a graphic EQ connected to my amp which I want to calibrate for a flat response. I've read somewhere that you can't calibrate a EQ by ear using test tones (different frequencies at same volume) but I'm wondering if I can connect my laptop to a mic and run a dB meter program on it in order to accurately depict the sound of the test tones. Using the dB meter, I can then set my EQ properly so that all the tones sound the same.

Will this technique work? I dont need perfect calibration, I just want it to be reasonable calibrated.

Comment: Do the speakers sound bad/wrong without the EQ?  If you only need reasonably calibrated speakers, your ears are probably sufficient to to direct your EQing.

Comment: It sounds good now... I'm just wondering if it would sound better if the speakers produced the same sound as the "artist intended".

So will my technique of using the mic and test tones work?

Answer (score 3):

If you know the curve for the mic you're using, then you should at least be able to determine what response you have now, which would tell you if you need to make EQ changes. Doing it band by band might be a bit tedious, but you won't do it often, so...

The gold standard is something like an Ivie sound analyzer, which uses "pink noise" as the sound source, and one or more calibrated microphones as pickups. You can monitor the acoustic properties of the room, from different positions, and see changes in EQ reflected in real time across the entire spectrum.

They're too expensive for casual use, but you may be able to rent one, or hire someone who owns one for a nominal fee.

Comment: Gold standard? This is a home stereo, not a studio setup.

I dont have the curve for my mic (its pretty old) so I'm stuck with my ears.